# show span in html with a javascript function with onclick involving random generator

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I apologize if the title sounds a little confusing, essentially, I am trying to figure out how to get a span to appear and/or swap depending on a random generator. in one of my classes involving riddles, I was able to get the text to disappear and reappear upon clicking the question. (see example below)

```js
var isVisible = new Array();
isVisible[0] = false;
isVisible[1] = false;

function revealAnswer(answerId, answer, indexNum){
    if(isVisible[indexNum]==false){
 var spanAnswer = document.querySelectorAll(".answers");
 for(i=0;i < spanAnswer.length ; i++){
 spanAnswer[i].innerHTML = '';
 }
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = answer;
    isVisible[indexNum]=true;
    console.log(answerId);
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = "";
    isVisible[indexNum]=false;
    }
}
```

```html
 <h5>Question 1</h5>
 <p onClick="revealAnswer('answer1','When it is turned into the teacher', 0)">When is homework not homework?</p><br/>
 <span id="answer1" class="answers"></span><br/>
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to apply that a random "hit or miss" generator to some button clicks that I have set up in another page (see below) I want the text to appear in the center of my "content div" which I can take care of in CSS.

```js
// javascript file for gun tutorial//
window.onload=function()
{
 var extraAmmo = 210;
 var maxAmmo = 30;
 var currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
 
 var extraAmmoHud = document.getElementById("extra-ammo");
 var currentAmmoHud = document.getElementById("current-ammo");
 
 var shootButton = document.getElementById("shoot-button");
 var unloadButton = document.getElementById("unload-button");
 var reloadButton = document.getElementById("reload-button");
 
 var gunShot = new Audio('GunShot.mp3')
 var gunShotAuto = new Audio('GunShotFullAuto.mp3')
 var gunReload = new Audio ('GunCockingFast.wav')
  refreshScreen();
 
 shootButton.onclick=function()
 {
  if(currentAmmo > 0)
  {
   currentAmmo--;
   gunShot.play();
   refreshScreen();
  }
 }
 unloadButton.onclick=function() 
 {
     if (currentAmmo > 0)
  {
            unloadTimer = setTimeout(unloadButton.onclick, 65)
         currentAmmo--;
   gunShotAuto.play()
         refreshScreen();
     } 
  else unloadTimer = null;
 }
 reloadButton.onclick=function()
 {
  var difference = getDifference();
  if(extraAmmo >= difference)
  {
   currentAmmo += difference;
   extraAmmo -= difference;
   gunReload.play()
  }
  else
  {
   currentAmmo += extraAmmo;
   extraAmmo -= extraAmmo;
  }
  refreshScreen();
  
  function getDifference()
  {
   return maxAmmo -currentAmmo;
  }
 }
 function refreshScreen()
 {
  extraAmmoHud.innerHTML="Extra Ammo: " + extraAmmo;
  currentAmmoHud.innerHTML="Current Ammo: " + currentAmmo;
 }
}
```

```css
form {
 height:110px;
 width:940px;
 margin:0px;
}

#content {
 width:940px;
 height:940px;
 background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#shoot-button {
 width:115px;
 height:20px;
 margin-top:10px;
 background-color:green;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid #006400;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#unload-button {
 width:115px;
 height:20px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-color:yellow;
 color:black;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid #D4AF37;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#reload-button {
 width:115px;
 height:20px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid #DC143C;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#boxobuttons {
 float:left;
 height:110px;
 width:120px;
 padding:0px 10px;
}
#ammo-count {
 float:right;
 height:110px;
 width:240px;
 line-height:25px;
 text-align:center;
 color:red;
 font-weight:bolder;
 font-size:20px;
}
.accuracy {
color:#FF0000;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
text-align:center;
display:block;
margin: auto;
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px #DD0000;
}
```

```html
 <div id="content">
 <span id="Hit" class="accuracy"></span>
 <span id="Miss" class="accuracy"></span>
 </div>
 <form>
 <div id="boxobuttons">
  <input type="button" value="Shoot" id="shoot-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Unload" id="unload-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Reload" id="reload-button" />
 </div>
 
  <div id="ammo-count">
   <p id="current-ammo"></p>
   <p id="extra-ammo"></p>
  </div>
 </form>
```

I am still unfamiliar with a lot of the Javascript codes and commands, but any help I can get is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you make your code in a demo at [tag:jsbin]?

Comment: would this help you Semsem?
http://jsbin.com/fopakoxase/1/

Comment: What text do you want to see in the center?

Comment: The text I want displayed is either the words "Hit" or "Miss"

Comment: Ah alright, so the player presses the shoot button and randomly it'll be a hit or miss which will then show in the center, is that right?

Comment: That is correct. I do apologize if I wasn't very descriptive when I initially talked about my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since it's a random game, we'll need a random function somewhere. It's only hit or miss so generating 0 or 1 randomly will do just fine:

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

`rnd` will be either 0 or 1, assume 0 is hit and 1 a miss or the other way around.

Now we have two spans which we want to show in the center based on the generated random. So we can have their parent (`<div id="content">`) to have `position: relative;`. Now the spans both have `display: none;` at the beginning and are absolutely positioned. Whether it's a hit or miss we'll show one and hide the other.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/yfkahxz1/)

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    /* other styles */
}
.accuracy {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 45%; /* change so you're happy with the position */
    top: 45%;
    /* other styles */
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var shootButton = document.getElementById("shoot-button");
var hitSpan = document.getElementById('Hit');
var misSpan = document.getElementById('Miss');
var numShot = document.getElementById('numShot');
var numHit = document.getElementById('numHit');
var numMiss = document.getElementById('numMiss');
var shots = 0;
var miss = 0;
var hit = 0;

shootButton.onclick = function () {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    refreshScreen(rnd);
}

function refreshScreen(n) {
    shots++;
    numShot.innerHTML = shots;
    if(n) {
        hit++;
        hitSpan.style.display = "block";
        misSpan.style.display = "none";
        numHit.innerHTML = hit;
    }
    else {
        miss++;
        misSpan.style.display = "block";
        hitSpan.style.display = "none";
        numMiss.innerHTML = miss;
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for a delay in responding Samurai, I am trying to get the javascript code to work with my website based on the examples you provided and applying them to my page. I am quite a slow typer, however I will do my best to respond with any success or issues I am encountering.

Comment: No worries, take your time :)

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/biloxuxeyi/1/
so far, the only two issues I am running into is that "miss++" isn't being defined and it is hiding my HUDs for my "current ammo" and "extra ammo"

Comment: Well you don't seem to have defined them anywhere. at the beginning of `window.onload=function(){` add `var hit = 0;` and `var miss = 0;`

Comment: holey moley, i jumped out of my seat. I had set in place some sounds for the buttons that scared me I didn't anticipate the reload of the webpage to cause the "shoot" button to trigger the sound and action. so I start with 1 round expended.

P.S. Reference to future self, lower volume on computer.

Comment: I appeared to have fixed that problem with the shoot button automatically triggering it's function upon refreshing the webpage, however, the word "Miss!" still appears before I even press any of my buttons.

Comment: Maybe you can post the new link so I can check then? :)

Comment: You're calling `refreshScreen();` right in your `window.onload` which means it calls the function onload. You might want to comment that line. Not sure if it changes other stuff, but we can handle them afterwards.

Comment: turning it into a comment did help, however at the same time, it initially hides the current and extra ammo HUDs until you click one of the buttons, then it reveals and stays revealed.

Comment: After commenting that refreshScreen(), add these two lines right BEFORE `shootButton.onclick`:   `extraAmmoHud.innerHTML="Extra Ammo: " + extraAmmo;
  currentAmmoHud.innerHTML="Current Ammo: " + currentAmmo;`

Comment: that solved the problem. Thanks a whole bunch for sticking with me. now I will work on styling the "accuracy" div class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76766/discussion-between-steven-ledoux-and-samurai).

Comment: disregard the help in the chat Samurai, I was able to figure something out, I had to add another variable and change the last portion in my javascript file from an "else" statement to an "else if"